# EF6 code first with devart doesn't create index

Tags: entity-framework-6, ef-code-first, devart

Following setup:
dotConnect for Oracle 9.5.454.0
EF 6.2.0
.NET 4.6.1
oracle 12c

We defined our models with the fluent API.
When the tabels are created is everything fine except that there are no indexes created.

```
[Table(nameof(Preisliste) + "n")]
public class Preisliste
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int PreislisteId { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [MaxLength(16)]
    [Index(IsUnique = true)]
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got the solution.
I forgot to set the initializer (did it in the context-constructor):

```
Database.SetInitializer(new MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion<EntityContext, Migrations.Configuration>());
```

After this my indexes got created.

Comment: That is correct. Indices could be created only via EF Migrations, you can use both scenarios: AutomaticMigrationsEnabled = true/false. In case of automatic migrations, you should use MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion (like you did).